# Cannot import frameworks on new swift files when using cocoapods

Tags: swift, cocoapods

Here is my podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'App' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'

  # Pods for App

  target 'AppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'AppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

I then run pod install. I open the pods workspace as per usual.

Now in my AppDelegate.swift I can import frameworks without issue

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase
import FirebaseCore
import Fabric
import Crashlytics
```

In my ViewController.swift, I can again import frameworks without issue

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
```

The issue is when I get to my new view controller, called HomeController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
```

It cannot find the frameworks, however it builds and runs fine. Just annoying as I lose code completion issues and have error warnings.

[image]

Not sure why it works on two files but not the third, it also builds and runs fine so seems like IDE issue rather than actual code/framework reference issue

Just looking at tips to resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the target membership of this new file to see if has the same as 2 previous one.

Select the file -> File Inspector -> Target Membership

Comment: Thanks, simple as taking it out of the test and ui tests target, assume i have to identify in podfile, tests and UItests will need those frameworks also

Comment: For tests, see the workaround at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/58